# Control volume from Azure machine

Tags: azure, windows-10, rdp

I am starting up with **Azure**.

Got one Azure machine with *Windows 10*.

Logged in with *RDP*.

But not able to control volume with in *RDP* window.

I have to go back to my original window and change volume.

And volume button in the RDP window is does nothing when clicked:

[image]

When I opened **Adjust system volume**:

[image]

Getting **No audio device installed** message:

[image]

How can be the volume controlled from Azure machine logged in from RDP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working after setting up **Sounds**.

Right clicked on speaker icon in system tray, the below menu appeared:

[image]

Clicked on **Sounds**, below pop-up appeared:

[image]

Clicked *Yes* to enable **Windows Audio Service**, below box appeared:

[image]

Cliked *Ok* to set the scheme.

Now I am able to play music and listen. Can control volume.